# Error 424 when Passing workbook to function in Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Using VBA in Access, I am attempting to pass a Excel workbook to another function.

I create the workbook using the following (snipped)

```
Dim Wbk             As Object
Dim sht             As Object
Dim xl              As Object

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set Wbk = xl.Workbooks.Open(OutputFileName)
Set sht = xl.Worksheets("qryTemp")
```

Using the above I am able to manipulate the Excel instance.

However I trying and pass the instance to another function using

```
OutputLog (xl)
```

and then

```
Function OutputLog(xl As Variant) As String
    xl.Application.Visible = True
End Function
```

...I get Error 424 Object required

Comment: Shouldn't you define x1 in the parameters as type Object?

Comment: @RobAnthony A `Variant` can be anything, including a reference to an object, so this is valid. Defining it as an `Object` would only take a tiny bit less memory, since a `Variant` also needs to store its type.

Comment: But then you are using it as an object without converting it to an object, which is why I suspect you are getting the error.

Comment: @RobAnthony you don't need to convert it to anything, the code is valid. Try the following (sorry for bad formatting in comments): `Public Sub TestVariant()
    Dim a As Application
    Set a = Application
    TestVariantPart2 a
End Sub

Public Sub TestVariantPart2(a As Variant)
    Debug.Print a.Build
End Sub`

Comment: Change `OutputLog (xl)` to `OutputLog xl`.

Comment: @BrakNicku This works - thank you. If you post as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

`OutputLog (xl)`

Using parenthesis here converts `Object` (`Application`) to simple type (`String` "Excel Application").

Correct versions are:

`OutputLog xl`

`Call OutputLog(xl)`

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a) you can find detailed information about calling procedures in VBA.